# SSRS web services fire a data subscriptions

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is there any way to fire off a data subscription from using the SSRS web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the SSRS web services do not support running data subscriptions.  If you want to run subscriptions through a web service call, you could expose a web service on a server that runs a sp_start_job command to the SQL Server Agent job for the associated schedule.  Sounds dangerous to me, but it is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Sure looks like it's possible:

http://geekswithblogs.net/shervin/archive/2007/06/20/113351.aspx